# Escape jinja2 syntax in a jinja2 template

Tags: flask, jinja2

I serve dynamic pages from Jinja2 templates in Flask. Now I am defining client-side templates in say, Jinja2-clone Nunjucks inside a script tag. Problem is, the client-side templates has syntax like `<% %>` that *Flask's* Jinja2 interpreter may interpret instead of rendering *verbatim*.

How can I make the entire block of scripts render verbatim?

Comment: **Note:** [tag:jinja] does this differently than [tag:twig]

Answer (score 273, accepted):

You can disable interpretation of tags inside a `{% raw %}` block:

```
{% raw %}

Anything in this block is treated as raw text,
including {{ curly braces }} and
{% other block-like syntax %}

{% endraw %}
```

See the [*Escaping* section](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#escaping) of the template documentation.

Comment: Is it possible to escape `{% endraw %}` line ?

Comment: @Vlad: not really, no. Don’t use exactly that text inside a raw block. You can use `{{ "{" }}` **outside** of a raw block to insert a literal curly brace followed by `% endraw %}`. If you are generating HTML, you could use HTML entities, like `&lbrace;`, `&percnt;` and `&rbrace;` instead of `{`, `%` and `}`, respectively.