# Vuejs populate a select element with an integer array

Tags: vue.js

I am tring to populate a html select field with numbers 1 to 100 using Vuejs. I have tried:

```
<div id="selector">
    <select id='row_selector' class="form-control" v-model="intArray"></select>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="path_to/vue.js"></script>
<script>
const MAX_VAL = 100; 
var numArray = Array.apply(null, {length: numArray}).map(Number.call, Number)
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#selector',
    data: {
        "intArray": numArray
    }
})
```

But the select element is empty. Do I need to use a directive to populate it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

View

```
<div id="app">
  <select v-model="selected">
    <option v-for="n in 100" :value="n">{{ n }}</option>
  </select>
  <p>
   Selected: {{ selected }}
  </p>
</div>
```

Component

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    selected: ''
  }
})
```

Comment: This partly works - I get a drop down that appears to be the correct size, but it is empty and nothing is printed next to 'Selected:' on selection?

Comment: Yes you are right the snipper works, I think the issue may be because I am using jinja2 tempating and the double braces causing a problem. Is there a way to just supply an array to the select element?

Comment: For Jinja2 you just have to add {% raw %} {% endraw %} around your Vuejs braces as per here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25359898/escape-jinja2-syntax-in-a-jinja2-template