# Concourse-CI templated files

Tags: templates, ansible, concourse

Using https://github.com/concourse/concourse:latest (4.2.2).

When I have a concourse-ci pipeline document I can use variables like ((var)) and {{var}} - however how do I pass in a file with variables such as

```
params:
  kubectl: | k8s/mykubectl # a template file that has variables
```

And then this file has contents such as:

```
run test --image=testme:((mytag)) --port ((myport))
```

How do I get concourse to replace those variables like for example the ansible template module will do..

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer to this using https://github.com/kelseyhightower/confd.

Basically built a docker image based on alpine with the confd binary in its PATH. Then use that image as a task resource to generate a file based on a template and some source of KVPS. With confd for your KVPs you can use consul, vault etc I used a .yml file that works just as well.

Hope that helps!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Concourse-CI, so I'm not sure that I understood your question correctly.
Nevertheless, if your question is: How in can I ensure that the Ansible will not interpret some part of a template file? I would suggest you the `raw` tag to escape a template block.

```
{% raw %}
run test --image=testme:((mytag)) --port ((myport))
{% endraw %}
```

Ref: [Escape jinja2 syntax in a jinja2 template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25359898/escape-jinja2-syntax-in-a-jinja2-template)

Comment: Hello thanks for your effort I do appreciate it however this was not an ansible question.

Comment: Missed! So sorry for the noise!